# Escape HTML "value" attribute for a select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select-menu

I have a select menu and I dynamically insert some values from a database:

```
 markup += '<option value=' + option["value"] + '>' + option["alias"] + '</option>';
```

some values, however, contain double quotes.  to try and get around this I tried:

```
markup += '<option value=' + JSON.stringify(option["value"]) + '>' + option["alias"] + '</option>';
```

For examples sake lets assume the value is 6"Rocket (*this is actually my problem child*)
When I try and read the value using Jquery `.val()` I always get 6.

What to do SO?

Comment: You should JS-escape the values you're using in JS if you're doing to do this using strings.

Comment: It's more than just JS-escaping here. I can't see how your option["value"] gets constructed...but you're escapin the value before you enclose it in quotes here `'<option value='`, it should be `"<option value='" + option["value"] + "'>" + option["alias"] + "</option>";`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy if I don't escape it than I get this <option value="6"" rocket="">6" Rocket</option>

Comment: @CrimsonChin you did not understand what i'm saying. [Please see my jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/LBggR/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Ok I follow, good example.  I swapped my single and double quotes like you and it worked.  I always thought It had no bearing on the output because in the end its just a string?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way of avoiding this problem is to DOM-sript rather than insert strings of HTML.

```
var sel = $('#some_dropdown');
...
$('<option />', {value: option.value, text: option.alias}).appendTo(sel);
```

Comment: Of course - anything you could craft yourself as an HTML string can be done also via DOM-scripting. In my code, I used a jQuery shortcut to set the attributes - passing an object as param 2 to the `$` function. There's also the `.attr()` method.